# What does it mean creating network in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

During reading tutorial about docker swarm I came across on follwing thing:

```
docker network create --opt encrypted --subnet 100.0.0.0/24 -d overlay net1
```

What does it do?
And how does it work internally? Maybe, does it create some network namespace?  What does it mean `overlay`.
Could someone explain these things?

Comment: As it’s a big field. I don’t have a answer on it. I won’t put it as a answer. I think you might need information about [docker network architecture](http://success.docker.com/article/networking). You will find more useful things there.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those options are explained in "[Use overlay networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)":

> The overlay network driver creates a distributed network among multiple Docker daemon hosts. This network sits on top of (overlays) the host-specific networks, allowing containers connected to it (including swarm service containers) to communicate securely. Docker transparently handles routing of each packet to and from the correct Docker daemon host and the correct destination container.

Regarding the `--opt encrypted` option:

> To encrypt application data as well, add --opt encrypted when creating the overlay network. This enables IPSEC encryption at the level of the vxlan. This encryption imposes a non-negligible performance penalty, so you should test this option before using it in production.
>
> When you enable overlay encryption, Docker creates IPSEC tunnels between all the nodes where tasks are scheduled for services attached to the overlay network.

The command [`docker network create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) includes [advanced options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#specify-advanced-options) like subnet:

> When you create a network, Engine creates a non-overlapping subnetwork for the network by default. This subnetwork is not a subdivision of an existing network. It is purely for ip-addressing purposes. **You can override this default and specify subnetwork values directly using the `--subnet` option**.